# How to use Mouseout Function in VBA with a condition Check?

Tags: vba

Hi I have a VBA application with a combobox selection option.One of the combobox option is Other which when user select that option an invisibled label will pops up and prompt the user to fill the txtOther control.now my question is how I can get rid of the prompted label and make it to invisible after user fill the txtOther and move(focused)in other control?
here is a shot of my app:

[image]

Thanks for your time and help

Comment: `label.visible = false` But why would you want the directions to disappear while they are still relevant?

Comment: Thanks for comment Daniel but I knew I can change the visibility to false.My question was which event handler can handle this?I mean after checking the user filled the form.The reason that I HAVE to do this is I have almost 15 comboboxes at UserForm and it looks very ugly having the 'Specify other' label every where on the form!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how often or when you want the check to be done. I couldn't find a good reference to show you all of this, but you can view your VBE.

Within the code behind your userform you can use events for the text box.
If you want the check done every time you leave the text box:

Use the TextBox_Exit event.

If you want it to fire whenever the contents are changed, used TextBox_Change. There's lots of options, but based on your explanation I'd probably use Exit.

This answer shows some [syntax examples for using the Textbox_Exit event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13400244/1316573).