# VBA code behaving differently when stepping

Tags: vba, excel, class

I am trying to write code that will handle the "change" event of any ComboBox on my userform.

I went by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940596/excel-vba-userform-execute-sub-when-something-changes) question's answer and created a separate class, etc.

However, it doesn't work. Using the same code on a new project works fine, this code on this project works sometimes when I use the "step by step" execution (F8), but when using normal running it doesn't.

Looking at other people's similar predicaments I added "DoEvents" but that didn't help.

This is my code in the UserForm

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim ComboBox_Collection As Collection
Dim ctrl As Control
Dim cbc As ComboBox_Class

Set ComboBox_Collection = New Collection
    For Each ctrl In UserForm1.MultiPage.Pages(2).Controls
    DoEvents
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "ComboBox" Then
            DoEvents
            Set cbc = New ComboBox_Class
            Set cbc.Control = ctrl
            ComboBox_Collection.Add cbc
            DoEvents
        End If
    Next ctrl
Set cbc = Nothing

End Sub
```

And the class module, named "ComboBox_Class":

```
Private WithEvents TriggerComboBox As MSForms.ComboBox

Public Property Set Control(CB As MSForms.ComboBox)
    Set TriggerComboBox = CB
End Property

Private Sub TriggerComboBox_Change()
    MsgBox ("yay")
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you'd like to have happen?

Comment: @ScottMarcus, I want to have a simple code that will handle the "change" event for all controls of a given type on a userform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ComboBox_Collection` needs to be a Global variable (at least, Global to your form's code module), or it will disappear/go out of scope as soon as your `UserForm_Initialize` Sub is finished executing

Comment: Thanks! That was it, I moved the collection to the Module and made it public, now it works!

Comment: @mathgenius You don't need to make it `Public` unless you need to access it from outside the class. And even if you need to access it outside the class, you should be exposing *a copy of it* (an array perhaps) as a `Public Property Get` member, to preserve proper encapsulation.