# Add one function to many controls

Tags: vba, excel, controls

Let's say I have a user form with 5 rows. Each row consists of multple controls, for an example:

```
<Text field> | <Text field> | <Combo box>
```

When the value of the first control/column (text field) is changed in either of the rows, I have a function I would like to call. Is this possible without making five seperate `_Change` functions (one for each row)?

Comment: Will the function that is called upon affect a specific control (like the one you changed, or the ones in the same row), or is it something global (like printing the time into one particular textbox)?

Comment: It will affect specific controls, but not the ones that calls the functions. For example it could affect a summary text field, showing the sum of alle the values in the first column (if all the inputs where numeric).

Comment: kk. In the specific case of a `SUM`-Field, you could think about adding a `.ControlSource` with `[Text0]+[Text1]+....` to **that one specific** sum field (manually or with a loop over your controls). No need to mess with the events of your inputfields then. For a more complex function that requires VBA, see my post below.

Comment: But is there anyway to trigger an update of that specific field, when one of the controls (text fields) changes? Maybe like a way to check for any changes in the entire form?

Answer (score 0):

There is a reasonably quick, but unreasonably dirty way of adding Eventhandlers to several controls...

i) define the function you want to call with `Change`. Afaik it has to be a `Public Function` in a normal module

ii) create an Access-makro (not VBA) with a `RunCode`-Event that calls your function.

[image]

iii) add the event to your controls, either in your design view or with something like

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Dim ctl
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        With ctl
            If .ControlType = acTextBox Then
                .OnChange = "Makro1"
            End If
        End With
    Next ctl        
End Sub
```

**Note:**

- the above code adds the event to all textboxes (due to me being lazy). swap the `If .ControlType = acTextBox Then` out for a check of your liking. You could use tags, smart-tags, simple name conventions like `tbx_c1r1` or control arrays, if you're fancy
- this gets considerably harder if your function includes the `Caller` in some way. Make sure to post your function, maybe we can figure out a way something.

Hope this helps! I'll be glad if someone comes up with a smarter approach.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Although dirty (as you said) it would actually fix my problem. I would prefer not having to use Access though (but maybe I have to).

Comment: i'm terribly sorry, i somehow missed that you got excel, and not access!

Comment: No worries. If you are interested, I found a possible solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940596/excel-vba-userform-execute-sub-when-something-changes - though I am strugling to make it work with `_Exit()` rather than just `_Change()`