# How to use a Class with a Collection of Controls

Tags: excel, vba

I tried adapting the solution in the link below to make a collection of text boxes allow numbers only.  I get no error but the class just doesn't apply to the textboxes.

[Excel VBA Userform - Execute Sub when something changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940596/excel-vba-userform-execute-sub-when-something-changes)

Class Module

```
Public WithEvents TextGroup As MSForms.TextBox

Public Property Set Control(tb As MSForms.TextBox)
    Set TextGroup = tb
End Property

Private Sub TextGroup_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
Select Case KeyAscii

Case 48 To 57
Case Else
KeyAscii = 0
End Select
End Sub
```

UserForm

```
Dim tbCollection As Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim obj As clsTextBox
    Dim ctrl As Control

    Set tbCollection = New Collection
        tbCollection.Add Me.tbAC
        tbCollection.Add Me.tbCR
        tbCollection.Add Me.tbHP

    For Each ctrl In tbCollection
        Set obj = New clsTextBox
        Set obj.Control = ctrl
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the obj objects in the collection, not the controls themselves

Untested:

```
Dim tbCollection As Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim obj As clsTextBox
    Dim arr
    Dim ctrl

    Set tbCollection = New Collection

    arr = Array(Me.tbAC, Me.tbCR, Me.tbHP) '<< edit: no Set

    For Each ctrl in arr
        Set obj = New clsTextBox
        Set obj.Control = ctrl
        tbCollection.Add obj
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I get a type mismatch error on the Set arr line.  I tried to Dim arr as Variant but still get the error.

Comment: Sorry typo on my part - there's no Set required for that assignment

Comment: Thank you that works great!  So at this point does it even make sense to use a Collection?  I could probably just loop through the array to assign the Class.

Comment: You need the class instances to stay "live" once your Initialize method ends: the global collection is a just a storage location for the objects so they don't go out of scope.

Comment: Ah, ok I think I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Can you listen for a TextBox exit event? Similarly to how a normal TextBox event would work? E.g.

```
  Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
        'Update a certain label based on the value of the TextBox
  End Sub
```

The following doesn't catch the exit event. Moreover, while I can see the .Name property of the TextBox which generated the event for MyTextBox in the locals window, I cannot access that info to determine which label to act on.

This class technique does catch some of the change events.

Class clsTextBox:

```
Private WithEvents MyTextBox As MSForms.TextBox

Public Property Set Control(tb As MSForms.TextBox)
    Set MyTextBox = tb
End Property

' Want to handle this event, but it's not caught when exiting the TextBox control
Private Sub MyTextBox_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    'Debug.Print me.Control.name
    'Update a certain label based on the value of the TextBox
    Stop
End Sub

' Catching this event but can't identify the control which triggered it
Private Sub MyTextBox_Change()
    Debug.Print MyTextBox.Value ' <--- This prints the correct value
    Debug.Print Me.Control.Name ' <--- ERROR here on any variation of Me or MyTextBox
    'Update a certain label based on the value of the TextBox
    Stop
End Sub
```

I have a series of dynamically created controls which need listeners. Code follows:

```
  Option Explicit
  Dim tbCollection As Collection

  Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
  'Stop
  End Sub

  Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control
        Dim obj As clsTextBox
        Dim acftNumber As Long
        Dim mPage As MSForms.MultiPage ' Control
        Dim lbl_acftName As MSForms.Label
        Dim lbl_currentHrs As MSForms.Label
        Dim lbl_hrsDUE As MSForms.Label
        Dim lbl_dateXFRIn As MSForms.Label
        Dim lbl_dateXFROut As MSForms.Label
        Dim lbl_hrsOnXFROut As MSForms.Label
        Dim txb_currentHrs As MSForms.TextBox
        Dim txb_hrsDUE As MSForms.TextBox
        Dim txb_dateXFRIn As MSForms.TextBox
        Dim txb_dateXFROut As MSForms.TextBox
        Dim txb_hrsOnXFROut As MSForms.TextBox
        Dim i As Double
        Dim pgName As String
        Dim acftName As String
        'Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control

        ' Correct for border size calculations bug in Excel 2016
        Me.Height = 249.75
        Me.Width = 350.25

        acftNumber = Range("aircraft").Count ' Some unknown value betweet 3 and 10
        Set mPage = Me.multipage_file_week 'set Multipage variable

        For i = 1 To acftNumber
              'set name/title for new page
              pgName = "pg_acft_" & i
              acftName = Range("aircraft").Cells(i, 1).Value

              'mPage.Pages.Add pgName, pgTitle

              With mPage 'add acft tab
                    ' add the aircraft page to the multipage
                    .Pages.Add pgName, acftName

                    ' Aircraft Name Label
                    Set lbl_acftName = .Pages(i).Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lbl_acftName_" & i, True)
                    With lbl_acftName
                          .Caption = acftName
                          .Font = "Arial"
                          .Font.Size = 12
                          .Font.Bold = True
                          .Left = 10
                          .Width = 55
                          .Top = 0
                    End With

                    ' Current Hours Label and TextBox
                    Set lbl_currentHrs = .Pages(i).Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lbl_currentHrs_" & i, True)
                    With lbl_currentHrs
                          .Caption = "Current Asset Hours:"
                          .TextAlign = fmTextAlignRight
                          .Font = "Arial"
                          .Font.Size = 10
                          .Font.Bold = False
                          .Left = 20
                          .Width = 120
                          .Top = 25
                    End With
                    Set txb_currentHrs = .Pages(i).Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "txb_currentHrs_" & i, True)
                    With txb_currentHrs
                          .Value = "16004.5"
                          .Text = "16004.5"
                          .Font = "Arial"
                          .Font.Size = 10
                          .Font.Bold = False
                          .Left = 150
                          .Width = 70
                          .Top = 25
                    End With


                    ' Hours DUE Label and TextBox
                    Set lbl_hrsDUE = .Pages(i).Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lbl_hrsDUE_" & i, True)
                    With lbl_hrsDUE
                          .Caption = "Hours next HMC DUE:"
                          .TextAlign = fmTextAlignRight
                          .Font = "Arial"
                          .Font.Size = 10
                          .Font.Bold = False
                          .Left = 20
                          .Width = 120
                          .Top = 50
                    End With
                    Set txb_hrsDUE = .Pages(i).Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "txb_hrsDUE_" & i, True)
                    With txb_hrsDUE
                          .Value = "16004.5"
                          .Text = "16004.5"
                          .Font = "Arial"
                          .Font.Size = 10
                          .Font.Bold = False
                          .Left = 150
                          .Width = 70
                          .Top = 50
                    End With

                    ' Date XFR In Label and TextBox
                    Set lbl_dateXFRIn = .Pages(i).Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lbl_dateXFRIn_" & i, True)
                    With lbl_dateXFRIn
                          .Caption = "Estimated arrival date:"
                          .TextAlign = fmTextAlignRight
                          .Font = "Arial"
                          .Font.Size = 10
                          .Font.Bold = False
                          .Left = 20
                          .Width = 120
                          .Top = 75
                    End With

                    Set txb_dateXFRIn = .Pages(i).Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "txb_hrsDUE_" & i, True)
                    With txb_dateXFRIn
                          .Value = "4/16/2019"
                          .Text = "4/16/2019"
                          .Font = "Arial"
                          .Font.Size = 10
                          .Font.Bold = False
                          .Left = 150
                          .Width = 70
                          .Top = 75
                    End With


                    ' Date XFR Out Label and TextBox
                    Set lbl_dateXFROut = .Pages(i).Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lbl_dateXFROut_" & i, True)
                    With lbl_dateXFROut
                          .Caption = "Estimated departure date:"
                          .TextAlign = fmTextAlignRight
                          .Font = "Arial"
                          .Font.Size = 10
                          .Font.Bold = False
                          .Left = 20
                          .Width = 120
                          .Top = 100
                    End With
                    Set txb_dateXFROut = .Pages(i).Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "txb_hrsDUE_" & i, True)
                    With txb_dateXFROut
                          .Value = "4/16/2019"
                          .Text = "4/16/2019"
                          .Font = "Arial"
                          .Font.Size = 10
                          .Font.Bold = False
                          .Left = 150
                          .Width = 70
                          .Top = 100
                    End With

                    ' Hours on XFR Out Label and TextBox
                    Set lbl_hrsOnXFROut = .Pages(i).Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lbl_hrsOnXFROut_" & i, True)
                    With lbl_hrsOnXFROut
                          .Caption = "Desired hours remaining on departure:"
                          .TextAlign = fmTextAlignLeft
                          .Font = "Arial"
                          .Font.Size = 10
                          .Font.Bold = False
                          .Left = 20
                          .Width = 170
                          .Top = 125
                    End With
                    Set txb_hrsOnXFROut = .Pages(i).Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "txb_hrsDUE_" & i, True)
                    With txb_hrsOnXFROut
                          .Value = "35"
                          .Text = "35"
                          .Font = "Arial"
                          .Font.Size = 10
                          .Font.Bold = False
                          .Left = 200
                          .Width = 35
                          .Top = 125
                    End With
              End With

              'Debug
              Debug.Print Me.multipage_file_week.Pages(i).Name & ":"
              For Each ctrl In Me.multipage_file_week.Pages(i).Controls
                    Debug.Print "  - " & ctrl.Name
              Next ctrl

        Next i
        mPage.Value = 0
        Me.Caption = FILE_WEEK_FORM_TITLE

        Set tbCollection = New Collection
        For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
              If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.TextBox Then
                    Set obj = New clsTextBox
                    Set obj.Control = ctrl
                    tbCollection.Add obj
              End If
        Next ctrl
        Set obj = Nothing
  End Sub
```