# Excel UserForm dynamic TextBox control exit events

Tags: excel, vba, events, userform

**UPDATE:** Upon further research in the object browser... it appears that an `MSForms.TextBox` implements neither the `.Name` property or `_Exit` events - only `_Change` events. Is there a way to determine which specific `TextBox` generated a change event?

Alternately is it possible to use the `MSForms.Control` with this technique? The `Control` object implements the `.Name` property and `_Exit` event.

---

Can you listen for a TextBox exit event? Similarly to how a normal TextBox event would work? E.g.

```
  Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
        'Update a certain label based on the value of the TextBox
  End Sub
```

The following doesn't catch the exit event. Moreover, while I can see the .Name property of the TextBox which generated the event for MyTextBox in the locals window, I cannot access that info to determine which label to act on.

This class technique was adapted from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5942200/2084052), and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47684598/2084052), which caught the change events.

Class clsTextBox:

```
Private WithEvents MyTextBox As MSForms.TextBox

Public Property Set Control(tb As MSForms.TextBox)
    Set MyTextBox = tb
End Property

' Want to handle this event, but it's not caught when exiting the TextBox control
Private Sub MyTextBox_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    'Debug.Print me.Control.name
    'Update a certain label based on the value of the TextBox
    Stop
End Sub

' Catching this event but can't identify the control which triggered it
Private Sub MyTextBox_Change()
    Debug.Print MyTextBox.Value ' <--- This prints the correct value
    Debug.Print Me.Control.Name ' <--- ERROR here on any variation of Me or MyTextBox
    'Update a certain label based on the value of the TextBox
    Stop
End Sub
```

I have a series of dynamically created controls which need listeners. Code follows:

```
  Option Explicit
  Dim tbCollection As Collection

  Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control
        Dim obj As clsTextBox
        Dim acftNumber As Long
        Dim mPage As MSForms.MultiPage ' Control
        Dim lbl_acftName As MSForms.Label
        Dim lbl_currentHrs As MSForms.Label
        Dim lbl_hrsDUE As MSForms.Label
        Dim lbl_dateXFRIn As MSForms.Label
        Dim lbl_dateXFROut As MSForms.Label
        Dim lbl_hrsOnXFROut As MSForms.Label
        Dim txb_currentHrs As MSForms.TextBox
        Dim txb_hrsDUE As MSForms.TextBox
        Dim txb_dateXFRIn As MSForms.TextBox
        Dim txb_dateXFROut As MSForms.TextBox
        Dim txb_hrsOnXFROut As MSForms.TextBox
        Dim i As Double
        Dim pgName As String
        Dim acftName As String

        ' Correct for border size calculations bug in Excel 2016
        Me.Height = 249.75
        Me.Width = 350.25

        acftNumber = Range("aircraft").Count 'Unknown value from 3 to 10

        Set mPage = Me.multipage_file_week 'set Multipage variable

        For i = 1 To acftNumber
              'set name/title for new page
              pgName = "pg_acft_" & i
              acftName = Range("aircraft").Cells(i, 1).Value

              'mPage.Pages.Add pgName, pgTitle

              With mPage 'add acft tab
                    ' add the aircraft page to the multipage
                    .Pages.Add pgName, acftName

                    ' Aircraft Name Label
                    Set lbl_acftName = .Pages(i).Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lbl_acftName_" & i, True)
                    With lbl_acftName
                          .Caption = acftName
                          .Font = "Arial"
                          .Font.Size = 12
                          .Font.Bold = True
                          .Left = 10
                          .Width = 55
                          .Top = 0
                    End With

                    ' Current Hours Label and TextBox
                    Set lbl_currentHrs = .Pages(i).Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lbl_currentHrs_" & i, True)
                    With lbl_currentHrs
                          .Caption = "Current Asset Hours:"
                          .TextAlign = fmTextAlignRight
                          .Font = "Arial"
                          .Font.Size = 10
                          .Font.Bold = False
                          .Left = 20
                          .Width = 120
                          .Top = 25
                    End With
                    Set txb_currentHrs = .Pages(i).Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "txb_currentHrs_" & i, True)
                    With txb_currentHrs
                          .Value = "16004.5"
                          .Text = "16004.5"
                          .Font = "Arial"
                          .Font.Size = 10
                          .Font.Bold = False
                          .Left = 150
                          .Width = 70
                          .Top = 25
                    End With


                    ' Hours DUE Label and TextBox
                    Set lbl_hrsDUE = .Pages(i).Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lbl_hrsDUE_" & i, True)
                    With lbl_hrsDUE
                          .Caption = "Hours next HMC DUE:"
                          .TextAlign = fmTextAlignRight
                          .Font = "Arial"
                          .Font.Size = 10
                          .Font.Bold = False
                          .Left = 20
                          .Width = 120
                          .Top = 50
                    End With
                    Set txb_hrsDUE = .Pages(i).Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "txb_hrsDUE_" & i, True)
                    With txb_hrsDUE
                          .Value = "16004.5"
                          .Text = "16004.5"
                          .Font = "Arial"
                          .Font.Size = 10
                          .Font.Bold = False
                          .Left = 150
                          .Width = 70
                          .Top = 50
                    End With

                    ' Date XFR In Label and TextBox
                    Set lbl_dateXFRIn = .Pages(i).Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lbl_dateXFRIn_" & i, True)
                    With lbl_dateXFRIn
                          .Caption = "Estimated arrival date:"
                          .TextAlign = fmTextAlignRight
                          .Font = "Arial"
                          .Font.Size = 10
                          .Font.Bold = False
                          .Left = 20
                          .Width = 120
                          .Top = 75
                    End With

                    Set txb_dateXFRIn = .Pages(i).Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "txb_hrsDUE_" & i, True)
                    With txb_dateXFRIn
                          .Value = "4/16/2019"
                          .Text = "4/16/2019"
                          .Font = "Arial"
                          .Font.Size = 10
                          .Font.Bold = False
                          .Left = 150
                          .Width = 70
                          .Top = 75
                    End With


                    ' Date XFR Out Label and TextBox
                    Set lbl_dateXFROut = .Pages(i).Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lbl_dateXFROut_" & i, True)
                    With lbl_dateXFROut
                          .Caption = "Estimated departure date:"
                          .TextAlign = fmTextAlignRight
                          .Font = "Arial"
                          .Font.Size = 10
                          .Font.Bold = False
                          .Left = 20
                          .Width = 120
                          .Top = 100
                    End With
                    Set txb_dateXFROut = .Pages(i).Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "txb_hrsDUE_" & i, True)
                    With txb_dateXFROut
                          .Value = "4/16/2019"
                          .Text = "4/16/2019"
                          .Font = "Arial"
                          .Font.Size = 10
                          .Font.Bold = False
                          .Left = 150
                          .Width = 70
                          .Top = 100
                    End With

                    ' Hours on XFR Out Label and TextBox
                    Set lbl_hrsOnXFROut = .Pages(i).Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lbl_hrsOnXFROut_" & i, True)
                    With lbl_hrsOnXFROut
                          .Caption = "Desired hours remaining on departure:"
                          .TextAlign = fmTextAlignLeft
                          .Font = "Arial"
                          .Font.Size = 10
                          .Font.Bold = False
                          .Left = 20
                          .Width = 170
                          .Top = 125
                    End With
                    Set txb_hrsOnXFROut = .Pages(i).Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "txb_hrsDUE_" & i, True)
                    With txb_hrsOnXFROut
                          .Value = "35"
                          .Text = "35"
                          .Font = "Arial"
                          .Font.Size = 10
                          .Font.Bold = False
                          .Left = 200
                          .Width = 35
                          .Top = 125
                    End With
              End With

              'Debug
              Debug.Print Me.multipage_file_week.Pages(i).Name & ":"
              For Each ctrl In Me.multipage_file_week.Pages(i).Controls
                    Debug.Print "  - " & ctrl.Name
              Next ctrl

        Next i
        mPage.Value = 0
        Me.Caption = FILE_WEEK_FORM_TITLE

        Set tbCollection = New Collection
        For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
              If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.TextBox Then
                    Set obj = New clsTextBox
                    Set obj.Control = ctrl
                    tbCollection.Add obj
              End If
        Next ctrl
        Set obj = Nothing
  End Sub
```

Comment: Inside your class `MyTextBox` is the associated textbox, not `Me` (that would be the instance of the class itself)

Comment: @TimWilliams I also tried that - same error. It appears that an `MSForms.TextBox` implements neither the `.Name` property or `_Exit` events - onlt `_Change` events. Is there a way to determine which specific `TextBox` generated the event?

Comment: If you can't get at the Name from MyTextBox then you could store it as another property/field in your class...

Answer (score 4):

`MSForms.Control` defines the `Enter` and `Exit` events: if you need to handle `TextBox.Change`, then you need two `WithEvents` variables:

```
Private WithEvents TextBoxEvents As MSForms.TextBox
Private WithEvents ControlEvents As MSForms.Control

Public Property Set Control(ByVal tb As Object)
    Set TextBoxEvents = tb
    Set ControlEvents = tb
End Property
```

`MSForms.Control` is also the interface through which you get to access properties like `Name`, `Top`, `Left`, `Visible`, etc.

Tip: Never type event handler procedure signatures by hand. Select the source interface from the dropdown in the upper-left corner of the code pane, then select an event to handle from the upper-right dropdown; let the VBE generate the members with the correct signature. If you're in a handler procedure and the upper-left dropdown says "(general)", you're not in an event handler.

---

#### EDIT

While the above code compiles fine and the `MSForms.Control` interface *does* expose the events we're looking to handle...

```
?TypeOf tb Is MSForms.Control
True
?TypeOf tb Is MSForms.TextBox
True
```

...there's a bit of COM hackery going on behind the scenes; there's enough smokes & mirrors for VBA to successfully compile the above, but, basically, you're looking at a glitch in The Matrix (Rubberduck's resolver has similar "nope" issues with MSForms controls): there isn't any obvious way to get VBA to bind a dynamic control object to its `MSForms.Control` events.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! However, the `Set ControlEvents = tb` line is giving an `Object or class does not support the set of events` error. I commented out all event handlers but it's still giving the error. Thoughts?

Comment: @ZephyrMays try declaring `tb` as an `Object`, and double-check the declared `As` type of the `WithEvents` field....

Comment: No luck with `Object`. I also tried to set the properties with two separate `Public Property Set` statements. It's getting stuck on the `MSForms.Control`

Comment: @ZephyrMays wah I'm missing something... immediate pane: `set o = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")`, then `?typeof o is MSForms.Control` - says True. Yet `Set thing.Control = o` -> doesn't support event. Weird...

Comment: An `MSForms.TextBox` inherits from `MSForms.Control`, right? My programming theory is a bit rusty but doesn't that mean a `TextBox` is a specific type of `Control`?

Comment: I found this after a deeper dive into google: http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/dynamic-forms/dynamic-event-handlers

Comment: @ZephyrMays looks like it's not about `MSForms.Control` events though. I found this: https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/468645-msforms-control-event-class.html - looks like they have a downloadable solution, but I'm not sure I'd trust some random download from some random forum.

Comment: An alternative approach may be to use `VBComponents().CodeModule.InsertLines` to write the handlers into  the module as the `TextBoxes` are created. Then just before the UserForm unloads, I could delete the lines.

Comment: That might work. Keep in mind that executing code that was generated at run-time, *after* the project was compiled, can't be debugged with breakpoints, makes the app vaguely more crash-prone, and requires elevated macro security settings (a specific permission to run VBIDE API stuff). Save often!

Answer (score 2):

With the help of the ConnectToConnectionPoint API you can catch the Event (Every Event, also Enter and Exit) for every control.

Have a look here: [Trigger Enter field behaviour through class for a control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930517/trigger-enter-field-behaviour-through-class-for-a-control/51936950#51936950)

For Exit it will be

```
Public Sub myExit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
Attribute myExit.VB_UserMemId = -2147384829
'code
End Sub
```