# Changing the ForeColor of a Textbox according to click, and returning it to its previous Forecolor when clicking another textboxt?

Tags: vba

I have Several Textbox and I want to change the Forecolor of the one that the user will click, but when the user clicks another textbox, the previous textbox have to change its Forecolor to the one before the click (defaul color).

I have the following for changing the color of the textbox:

```
Private Sub D8_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    D8.ForeColor = &H80000002
End Sub
```

But I don't know how to change it back to its previous forecolor when clicking another textbox.

Thanks

Comment: If you have a lot of text boxes and Brian's answer would be too much of a hassle or you want to reduce everything into one sub you can make a **Class Module** to capture all of your text boxes in one Sub then use the same Enter Exit idea to for each one. This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5942200/2632165) is perfect for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Enter and Exit events:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()
   TextBox1.ForeColor = &H80000002
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
   TextBox1.ForeColor = vbWindowText
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Enter()
   TextBox2.ForeColor = &H80000002
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
   TextBox2.ForeColor = vbWindowText
End Sub
```